# Janusgraph gremlin groovy condition check and script exit

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph

I use Janusgraph.   In my graph initialization groovy script, I would like to do a simple check, if the graph already exists, exit the script, else continue with the rest of the initialization.

when I run below code,  it complains that

groovysh_parse: 1: unexpected token: else @ line 1, column 1.

else {

Also, is there a command equivalent to System.exit(0)? The return command does not work seems like.

In addition, any good reference on gremlin-groovy would be appreciated.

Thanks

`

```
//Create a sessioned connection to the Gremlin Server
:remote connect tinkerpop.server conf/remote.yaml session
:remote console

//define graph name
graph_name = "graph1"

//check whether graph exists

if (ConfiguredGraphFactory.getGraphNames().contains("graph_name")) {
  println "graph already exists"
  return
}

else {
  map = new HashMap();
  map.put("storage.backend", "cql");
  map.put("storage.hostname", "127.0.0.1")
  map.put("index.search.backend", "elasticsearch")
  map.put("index.search.hostname", "127.0.0.1")
  ....
  map.put("graph.graphname", graph_name)
  ConfiguredGraphFactory.createConfiguration(new MapConfiguration(map))
  .... 

  graph = ConfiguredGraphFactory.open(graph_name)
  //Creat graph schema
  //Close all transactions
  graph.getOpenTransactions().forEach { tx -> tx.rollback() }

  mgmt = graph.openManagement()
  mgmt.getOpenInstances().forEach {
    if (it.reverse().take(1) != ")") {
      mgmt.forceCloseInstance(it)
    }
  }
  ....
  pk_id = mgmt.makePropertyKey('id').dataType(String.class).cardinality(org.janusgraph.core.Cardinality.LIST).make()
  pk_name = mgmt.makePropertyKey('name').dataType(String.class).cardinality(org.janusgraph.core.Cardinality.LIST).make()
  ....
  mgmt.commit()
  ConfiguredGraphFactory.close(graph_name)
}
```

`

Groovy code conditional checking if graph exists, if yes, exit the program else continue finish the rest of the code.

Comment: answered this on gremlin-users but figured i'd replicate the answer here so that the answer is here for others

Answer (score 1):

When writing scripts for Gremlin Console you have to pay extra attention to spacing.  So if you do:

```
if(1==1) {
  println "1"
}
else {
  println "2"
}
```

the groovy evaluator won't know that there is anything after that first closing brace and will start a new evaluation with "else {" which is invalid syntax. you would want to make sure you spacing was like:

```
if(1==1) {
  println "1"
} else {
  println "2"
}
```